# Add attributes to a igraph object by parsing a dataframe

Tags: r, igraph

I am creating an igraph object from a edge list and then adding attributes to the nodes.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    require(dplyr)
    library(readr)
    library(igraph)


#edge list    
    edge_df <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.edges", header = F, sep = " ", numerals="no.loss")

#attributes     

    full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.feat", header = F, numerals="no.loss")

#names of different attributes

    feat_desc_file_df <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.featnames")

    column_names <- append("nodeid",feat_desc_file_df)
    colnames(full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df)<-column_names

 #create a graph from edge list   

    g <- graph_from_data_frame(edge_df, directed = TRUE)

#add attribute to nodes by searching and matching

    V(g)$"0 gender:1"=full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df$"0 gender:1"[match(as.numeric(V(g)$name),as.numeric(levels(full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df$nodeid))[full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df$nodeid]
    )]
```

The first attribute in the dataframe (feat_desc_file_df) is "0 gender:1" which is added. But in the dataframe (feat_desc_file_df) there are 1318 attribute names. For each of these I have to search and match as i have for "0 gender:1" whats the best way

Comment: How should the entries like `o  gender:1` be interpreted? What node gets what gender value?

Comment: o gender:1 is the name of a column in dataframe full_ego_friends_feat_circles_df. the entries are in that column give what node what gender value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question. I think a simple solution may be to loop through the various columns of the attributes' table.

Then sort the attributes based on the matches with the vertex ids and set the attributes for each node using the set_vertex_attr function.

```
# Load data 
edgelist <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.edges", header = F, sep = " ", numerals="no.loss")
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
attribute_table <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.feat", header = F, numerals="no.loss")
attr_names <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/100129275726588145876.featnames")

attr_names <- append("id", attr_names)

names(attribute_table)<-attr_names

# Loop through the attribute dataframe to add an attribute at the time, using the set_vertex_attribute function. 

for (i in 2:length(attribute_table)){

  # Select attributes
  temp_attribute <- attribute_table[,c(1,i)]

  # Match the attribute id with the id of the graph vertexes
  sorted_attr<- temp_attribute[match(temp_attribute[,1], V(graph)$name),2]
  
  # Set attributes
  graph <- set_vertex_attr(graph, name = (names(attribute_table)[i]), 
                  index = V(graph), value = sorted_attr)

}
```